# how to include image in tex with its background set as transparent

Tags: graphics, backgrounds

I have some image a.jpg (say for example the below one) with some lines drawn in black over a white background. I am writing a tex document where i have set the background with

```
\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
    opacity=0.2,  
    contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{b.jpg}}
}
```

Now with the background as b.jpg, i am writing some text and in addition i want to embed the image a.jpg. I tried including this image using includegraphics. But with this, i get the white background of image a on top of b's background.
How can i include it (using includegraphics or some other way) so that black lines in image a.jpg are shown with background as b.jpg (& not the original background of a.jpg which is white thus effectively making the a's background as transparent).

[image]

Comment: I have not access to a computer now, but a wild guess is to try with PNG files with a correct alpha layer. JPG standard has no transparency.

Comment: @Rmano: Does that mean its not possible at all with the jpeg image ? As you told, i tried with a png image as well using ```\transparent{0.1}\includegraphics``` , but this resulted in transparency being applied for whole image rather than just the white background. Please let me know what is the way with png images & if its at all possible somehow with jpeg as well.

Comment: Use an external program to set the alpha for PNGs. LaTeX will only include it and is no image editor. With JPG it's impossible to separate fore- and background through alpha.

Comment: @TeXnician : Thanks for the info. Do you mean we need to edit the png image with some external program which can help me remove the white background ? Also if possible can you please point me to some program which can help me do that (setting the alpha for png). Does 'setting the alpha for png' here means removing the white background from png ?

Comment: Yes. Tools like GIMP can help you with that. And yes, setting the alpha (transparency) component for parts of the image means in your case making the white background transparent.

Comment: @TeXnician : can you please add your comments as answer so that i can accept it. Thanks.